# Need suggestion on launching different layouts and back button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

My requirement is to launch a setup wizard on first launch and open a list view on consecutive launch. The setup wizard will collect information to create users and related settings. The list view is a more of a tabbed view with tab content scrollable.

The setup wizard is of LinearLayout whereas the second launch should use TabHost. While I am using sharedPreferences to find out first launch etc, how to call different layouts. If I use setContentView based on the condition, the class has to extend TabActivity but it fails if setup wizard is launched as no TabHost is present. If I use intent to launch the different screens, should I have a dummy layout from which either setup or listing layouts are launched through intents? When back button is clicked, it goes back to the dummy layout. Any suggestions on how it should be designed?

Answer (score 0):

Have your main activity be the setup wizard, so when the user clicks on your program icon on Home Screen it will launch your setup wizard, then on onCreate of the setup wizard you check the preferences for first time, if first time you setContentView() and all, if not, then start your other activity and call finish() on the first.

So every time after the first time, your setup wizard will the called, then you kill it and start your real program activity.

If you call finish, the back button won't come back to the wizard.